# Play all button for multiple audio

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way of playing multiple audio with 1 play "all" button?

For example,

I have 2 different audio, I want both of them to play at the same time when I click a button. Is there such a way to do this? I can play audio for 1 button that is assigned to it.

Thank you!

Comment: Post the code how you are playing that single audio, so we can show you how could you adapt it.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, I am new to this lol. Don't usually ask for help as my questions gets answered with a google search but couldn't find anything. Btw, my code is really lengthy, as I work on small projects to enhance my programming.

Comment: @Alex - just post a complete and minimal example. All you need is a single button and a couple of `<audio>` elements. That you should do so and how is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a similar method to load the files using the audio tag.
One audio file is the footsteps and the other is the scream.

```js
var audio1 = $("#audio1")[0];
var audio2 = $("#audio2")[0];

$("#button").click(function() {
  audio1.play();
  audio2.play();
});
```

```css
a#button {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a#button:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio1" src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/dl.php?ext=wav&id=0514&button=GO%3E" type="audio/wav">Your browser does not support the &#60;audio&#62; element.</audio>
<audio id="audio2" src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/dl.php?ext=wav&id=0477&button=GO%3E" type="audio/wav">Your browser does not support the &#60;audio&#62; element.</audio>

<a id="button">PLAY ALL </a>
```